# How to Create rectangle with curve on top left and bottom left using css?

Tags: css

I want to create background like this. 
Rectangle with curve.

I tried using this css

```
.rect{
 border-radius:50%;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: -100px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: -100px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2rd1e045/3/

Comment: Thanks. Got distracted by [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356037/hi-i-need-a-regex-expression-in-angularjs-for-matching-file-path-similar-to-var).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.rect {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect">
  Filters
</div>
```

Not much else to say.

Answer (score 2):

Kindly check the code, it meet's the question expectation.
Kindly mark the question upvote to acknowledge combine effort of community.
Your problem was that you didn't use border-top-left-radius property.
For any question feel free to ask.
Thank's

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#rcorners1 {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #73AD21;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;    
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The border-radius Property</h1>

<p>Rounded corners for an element with a specified background color:</p>
<p id="rcorners1">Rounded corners!</p>


</body>
</html>
```